# Looking for sequences with certain conditions.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Are there sequences $a_n>0$, $p_n \subseteq (0,1)$ so that

(1) $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = \infty$

(2) $\lim_{n \to \infty} p_n =0$

(3) $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n}{n} = 0$

(4) $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n}{n p_n} = \infty$

(5) $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\log \frac{a_n}{n p_n}}{\sqrt{a_n}} = 0$

(6) $\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{n p_n}{a_n} \right)^{\alpha} \frac{\sqrt{a_n}}{\log \frac{a_n}{n p_n}} = \infty$ for all $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$?

I'm struggeling with the last condition. If $\alpha \le 0$ it is obvious from the other conditions that (6) holds. For $\alpha >0$ I just can't seem to find sequences so that $a_n \to \infty$ slow enough and $p_n \to 0$ slow enough that $n p_n \to \infty$ fast. I'm not even sure if such sequences exist but haven't been able to prove otherwise either.